# Create & burn an ISO Image from a source Blu-Ray under Linux

Tags: iso, dvd, dd, blu-ray, disk-ripping

My aim is to create an accurate, bit-for-bit identical copy of a Blu-Ray disc while leaving all the original content, DRM etc. untouched. How would I manage to do so using `dd` command to rip to .iso and to burn back to a blank BD?

I succeeded in creating accurate DVD copies by [following this particular approach](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Create_an_ISO_Image_from_a_source_CD_or_DVD_under_Lin).

My basic steps according to the above instructions were:

1. Running dd with the parameters for block size and volume size which results in an accurate, ready-to-burn ISO image.
2. Burning the ISO image to a blank DVD using dd
3. Verifying the DVD copy by re-ripping it to .iso (see step 1.) and comparing the resulting ISO image to the ISO image I used to burn the DVD (file size, MD5 checksum were identical)

As far as I know, I cannot read the block size and the volume size of a retail BD using the `isoinfo -d -i /dev/cdrom` command because of the fact that BDs are generally not in ISO 9960 format. Therefore, I followed my basic steps as usual but I just used the `dd if=/dev/cdrom of=test.iso` command without any bs and count arguments. As one might expect, my final comparison (step 3.) leaves me with two different ISO files (one larger file, different MD5 sums).

Does anybody have a solution to this? I assume some obligatory bs and count arguments are missing in my ripping routine - but how do I obtain the necessary information (Logical block size, volume size of BD) in the first place?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Note that doing this with commercial movie disc won't result in a playable BD, even if you successfully copy the data - the DRM is designed to prevent this kind of copying. Commercial BluRay movie discs include the DRM encryption keys on a special part of the disc, which can only be read. Since recordable blurays don't have this part of the disc, when you burn your ISO, the encryption keys won't be on your recorded disc, thus rendering it unplayable.

Comment: Like @JonasCz said, you won't have an easy time with this. You'd be better off trying to rip the BD into an mp4 and then re-create it.

Comment: What should work though, is ripping the movie and decrypting it, and burning it onto a new bluray, but not encrypted, you should not even need to reencode to mp4, just strip the encryption.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the block size by using `blockdev --getbsz /dev/sr0` where "/dev/sr0" may change, depending on the amount of drives you have and the block count by using `blockdev --getsz /dev/sr0`, multiplied by 512 and then divided by the block size.
You can test this using `isoinfo -d -i /dev/sr0` on a normal DVD.

From my understanding `dd` will work just fine, creating a perfect copy of your blue-ray, even with no size or count variables set.
These variables are only used when skipping unwritten parts of the disc, parts that physically exist but do not store information, as is common when the data isn’t as large as the disk.

I tested creating an ISO of a blue-ray without the size and count variables and using bit wise comparison `cmp` to compare it with the disc, and it didn’t give me any error.
I assume that the reason it didn’t work for you was that you burned it to yet another disc, which (as @JonasCz said) won't work due to copy-protection.

The ISO will play just fine, though.
I successfully opened and watched a blue-ray ISO using leawo on windows.

For example:

- `blockdev --getsz /dev/sr0` shows me 16142856.
- `blockdev --getbsz /dev/sr0` shows me 2048.
- 16142856 * 512 = 8265142272,
- 8265142272 / 2048 = 4035714.

This equals the output of `isoinfo -d -i /dev/sr0`
when used on a DVD:

- Logical block size is: 2048
- Volume size is: 4035714

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and congrats on the excellent first answer!  **:-)** Please also review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1034220/revisions) so your next answers will become even better!  **:-)**  You're a rep 11 user already!

Comment: @Fabby Nice way to welcome new users! This isn't obvious on Stackexchange. Wish many moderators would be like u

Comment: I'm not a mod: I'm a reviewer... @Stackcraft_noob  Mods are way too overworked to be nice. **:D :D :D**

Comment: @Fabby Nevermind! Nice to meet you