# Help with setting up custom ISO

Tags: boot, iso

I'm a Linux noob and would appreciate instructions on setting up a Linux iso or image I can burn to cd/dvd that includes guest additions installed, firewall with settings, virtual box installed and set up to run one or more OS'es, plus a few other add-ons like wireshark/snort - maybe even delete some apps I'll never use.

The goal is to produce a boot disc with a customized set of tools and capabilities, but one that cannot be compromised, while being able to save files to a usb and/or burn to cd/dvd.

I've dabbled with Mint and like the simplicity and reduced load on a 4mb RAM, 10yr old computer, but am open to other flavors of Linux. I also have an old PowerMacG4 I'd like to run Linux on, too. I also assume I might need different burns for 32bit or 64bit computers.

Do I need to set up my preferred system with all the pieces in place, then somehow create an iso/image from that existing system?

I plan on running it as a cd or dvd on older machines that don't let me force booting from a usb. I know this means a slower running system, but I don't know how to ensure a usb is not easily written to without getting into encryption.

I understand this approach will likely limit or prevent system updates, but if it's locked down by not allowing writing back to the disc, I can just create the ideal system on a separate hard drive and mount it periodically to update everything and burn a new disc.

Any guidance is appreciated. Is Cubic my only option or one at all?

Comment: I’m not sure what this has to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: I guess I need to find a Linux support site? I saw this question/answer and incorrectly thought I might get help.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/875316/create-burn-an-iso-image-from-a-source-blu-ray-under-linux?rq=1

Comment: Cubic only works with creating an Ubuntu ISO.  The name means `Custom UBuntu ISO Creator`.  So, if your main boot is Ubuntu on your USB, then yes, Cubic might be your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/a/49679)

Comment: Try this by following the link below [previous answered question relating to this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515310/can-startup-disk-creator-make-a-bootable-cd-dvd)

Comment: @Terrance, Cubic works with most Ubuntu based distros. (See [About Cubic](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki/About-Cubic)). However, only questions about official Ubuntu flavors are [on-topic at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The various answers cover everything I need for now.